# Merging two dataframes without repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that contain unique ID's, a review column (positive in one, and negative in the other) and a rating column (again one for positive and one for negative):

**df1:**

| unique_id | pos_review | pos_rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Great, would recommend... | 8 |
| 1 | "Really cool, you should go... | 7 |
| 2 | "I had a great time, you.. | 9 |
| 3 | "Good way to spend your night... | 8 |
| 4 | "I might go again for how good it was... | 9 |

**df2:**

| unique_id | neg_review | neg_rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Really boring... | 4 |
| 2 | "I'll never try this again... | 2 |
| 2 | "I would not recommend.. | 3 |
| 3 | "Could have been better... | 4 |
| 3 | "No one should ever go... | 1 |

I'm trying to combine the two so that the unique id's can line up, but if one had more reviews than the other, the missing review would result in a NaN value which I'd later replace with "No Review". So ideally I'd end up with:

**df3:**

| unique_id | pos_review | pos_rating | neg_review | neg_rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Great, would recommend... | 8 | "Really boring... | 4 |
| 1 | "Really cool, you should go... | 7 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | "I had a great time, you.. | 9 | "I'll never try this again... | 2 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | "I would not recommend.. | 3 |
| 3 | "Good way to spend your night... | 8 | "Could have been better... | 4 |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | "No one should ever go... | 1 |
| 4 | "I might go again for how good it was... | 9 | NaN | NaN |

I've tried using `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='unique_id', how='inner')`, but that just repeats the first review of my df1 for every review in my df2, like such (looking at unique_id 2 below):

| unique_id | pos_review | pos_rating | neg_review | neg_rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Great, would recommend... | 8 | "Really boring... | 4 |
| 1 | "Really cool, you should go... | 7 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | "I had a great time, you.. | 9 | "I'll never try this again... | 2 |
| 2 | "I had a great time, you.. | 9 | "I would not recommend.. | 3 |
| 3 | "Good way to spend your night... | 8 | "Could have been better... | 4 |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | "No one should ever go... | 1 |
| 4 | "I might go again for how good it was... | 9 | NaN | NaN |

Any ideas on how I can get the above df3?

Comment: Please post the tables as "code" so they are legible.

Comment: Sorry about that! Had spacing in my heading separator

Comment: I think I'd question what you are trying to achieve by getting that output table. I feel like it will be a band-aid type workaround to your actual goal. Like is there any reason you don't just want a merged table with just the review and score and then a column for pos/neg based on >5/< 5 or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cumulative counter as second argument for your `groupby`.

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    df1,df2, 
    left_on=['unique_id',df1.groupby('unique_id').cumcount()],
    right_on=['unique_id',df2.groupby('unique_id').cumcount()],
    how='outer')
```

delivers the desired result

Comment: You're an absolute hero!

Answer (score 0):

Change `inner` to `outer` , and create the sub key with `cumcount`

```
df1['key'] = df1.groupby('unique_id').cumcount()
df2['key'] = df2.groupby('unique_id').cumcount()
df3 = df1.merge(df2,on = ['unique_id','key'],how='outer').sort_values('unique_id')
```

Out[134]:

```
   unique_id             pos_review  pos_rating  key neg_review  neg_rating
0          1  reatwouldrecommend...         8.0    0    Really         4.0
1          1                 Really         7.0    1       NaN         NaN
2          2                    had         9.0    0      I'll         2.0
5          2                    NaN         NaN    1         I         3.0
3          3                   Good         8.0    0     Could         4.0
6          3                    NaN         NaN    1        No         1.0
4          4                      I         9.0    0       NaN         NaN

# you can also drop the key column with df3 = df3.drop(['key'],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated after @HenryEcker pointed out that `append` is to be depreciated.

I would use `pd.concat` instead of `DataFrame.merge` since 'unique_id' is not actually unique in the sense of a table value.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Mabye `merge` is confusing your sense of what the output table should be. I think your example of your ideal df3 needs to include additional rows with NaNs

E.g. for `unique_id = 1` you should have three rows:

- two with NaNs in the negative columns
- one with NaNs in the positive columns

I'm not sure why you would assign a negative review to only one one row of unique_id = 1 but not to others. Best to just keep all rows and use NaNs in all where appropriate

Then if you want to aggregate use `DataFrame.groupby`. E.g. for the mean rating

```
grouped_mean = df3.groupby('unique_id').mean()
```

Note that this would give you a new df with a mean for the negative reviews and a mean for the positive reviews since they are in different columns in df3

Comment: Just for reference `append` was [deprecated in 1.4.0 and will be removed in a future version](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append)

Comment: Ah thanks @HenryEcker, I'll update the answer using `concat`